# JavaScript getElementByID - error in JavaScript code (field is left blank but not turning red on click)

Tags: javascript, button, textbox, getelementbyid

I have the following JavaScript code, it appears to be correct.

I simply want, on button Click, for the background of the textbox to turn 'red', if the textbox is left blank.

Can someone point out the error in the below code.

```js
function validate(){
  if (document.getElementById("textbox_1").value==' '){
    document.getElementById("textbox_1").style.backgroundColor='red'; 
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
   NAME:<INPUT TYPE="Text" SIZE="15" VALUE="" ID="textbox_1" />
   <INPUT TYPE="Button" VALUE="SEND" onClick="Validate()" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uppercase/Lowercase matters (in function name). You also should compare against empty string not blank space:

```html
<script>
  function validate(){
    var el = document.getElementById("textbox_1");
    if (el.value.trim()==''){
      el.style.backgroundColor='red'; 
    }
    else{
      el.style.backgroundColor=''; 
    }
  }
</script>
NAME:<INPUT TYPE="Text" SIZE="15" VALUE="" ID="textbox_1">
<INPUT TYPE="Button" VALUE="SEND" onClick="validate()">
```

Comment: Thank you - the value.trim() in particular is helpful.

Comment: @MissComputing, you are welcome, it always good practice to use `trim()` before comparing the value:)

Answer (score 1):

You have written he function name wrong

```js
function validate(){
if (document.getElementById("textbox_1").value=='')
    document.getElementById("textbox_1").style.backgroundColor='red';   
}
```

```html
NAME:<input type="Text" size="15" value="" id="textbox_1">
<input type="Button" value="SEND" onClick="validate()">
```

Answer (score 1):

function name will be validated not Validate.Html Uppercase function name Validate/Lower case in validate JS

```js
function validate(){
if (document.getElementById("textbox_1").value==''){
    document.getElementById("textbox_1").style.backgroundColor='red';   
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>

</head>
<body>
NAME:<INPUT TYPE="Text" SIZE="15" VALUE="" ID="textbox_1">
<INPUT TYPE="Button" VALUE="SEND" onClick="validate()">
</body>
</html>
```